# Simulink SFunction Builder Bus input value

Tags: c, simulink, bus, s-function

I'm trying to understand how to access and use the Bus system with custom S-Function Blocks. I built a very basic S-Function using the S-Function Builder which has **no input and one Bus output**. The Bus is a struct consisting only of one field of type double. This **works just fine**.

No I tried to connect its output to a newly created block (also with help of the S-Function Builder) which has **one Bus input and no output**. It should write the value of the only field inside the struct to the console using `mexPrintf`. But **the value is always 0 (zero)**

I set the output of the first block like that in the output wrapper function *(works fine)*:

```
out0->data = 12;
```

and I try to get the input value inside the other block like this *(prints always 0)*:

```
real_T insig = in0->data;
mexPrintf("Got a %d", insig);
```

Answer (score 1):

Stupid error - I was using `%d` instead of `%f` for printing a double value...